# during installation it says visual C++ 2008 is not installed

Tags: c++

When I try to install a new application, it says Visual C++ 2008 SP1 is not installed and it is necessary.

I have noticed that visual c++ 2005, 2008 and 2010 both 64 bit and 32  bit are already these.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled twice.

.Net framework 3.5.1 and .Net framework 4 client profile is installed.

I'm trying to install my app in Windows Server 2008 R2 64bits. the new app which im tryiong to install is a 64 bit version.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: Are you trying to install the "debug" mode by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Please see if VS2008 SP1 is installed. GoTO Visual Studio "Help" menu and click on "About Microsoft Visual Studio".
You can try installing VS SP1 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=10986.

Comment: Im getting this error:

A compatible version of Visual Studio 2008 was not detected on the system. This update is designed for only the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (ENU) product family, and is not compatible with any Express editions.

Comment: just to add one more thing. whenever i deinstall VC++ and restart my machine it is again getting installed automatically. i'm not able to post the screenshot of my control panel.

Comment: see if this can help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88385fe1-f967-476f-af34-f1d46965cc27/unable-to-uninstall-visual-studio-2008-vssetupmsi-can-not-be-opened